# For square matrices $A$, $B$, is $AB=I$ sufficient that $A$ and $B$ are inverse of each other?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If $AB = I$ then $BA = I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i)

If $A$ and $B$ are two square matrices, and we know $AB=I$ where $I$ is the identity matrix. Is it sufficient that $BA=I$ as well so that $A$ and $B$ are inverse matrices of each other?

Just found out that this is a duplicate question.

Comment: @EuYu Good to know that. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, something stronger is true. Suppose that $A$ is invertible, and that $AB=I$. Then, $B=A^{-1}$ so that $BA=A^{-1}A=I$. Now, if $AB=I$, then $\det(A)\det(B)=1$ so that $\det(A)\ne 0$. So, $A$ is invertible. From this, you see that if *just* $AB=I$ then $A$ is invertible and $B=A^{-1}$.

Comment: Just to comment that this only works for square matrices of finite order.